# MySQL Statement to call the data out

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help with my MySQL statement. i want to call the data from my MySQL table with specific condition. and i wish to present the data into a chart by using php.
For example, here is my table.

```
11003 trid(primary key)             1(tid)  Adventure(name)      US(location)      2014(date)   5(duration)     1003(id)   romex(fname) jen(lname)   approved(pending)
11006 trid(primary key)             1(tid)  Adventure(name)      US(location)      2014(date)   5(duration)     1006(id)   siew(fname)  siew(lname)  approved(pending)
21003 trid(primary key)             2(tid)  Yourfuture(name)     US(location)      2014(date)  1(duration)     1003(id)   romex(fname) jen(lname)   approved(pending)
```

i want the data to count the total of people will going in each training. and list the name out.

Expected result is something like this.

```
Adventure                   romex jen           
                            siew  siew          total 2

Yourfuture                  romes jen           total 1
```

the pending can be 'decline' or 'approved' when approved mean they are going. 
my current MySQL statement is this.

```
SELECT name, date, fname, lname FROM `trainingrequest` WHERE pending = 'Approved'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the total people in one of two ways:

`select count(*) as c from trainingrequest where pending = 'Approved'`

This will return the total number of approved records. To narrow it down you will need to use an event id or such

`select count(*) as c from trainingrequest where pending = 'Approved' and name = 'adventure';`

or you could just grab all the data you need and count the rows in php. The first method will require two calls to the database. Counting the rows in PHP will require one call to the database!

It looks like you also want to `GROUP BY` your data

`select * from trainingrequest` where .... GROUP BY location;